# Using an input box and msg box to search for data in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, search, inputbox, msgbox

I'm working on a sub that requires me to make it so that a user can search for their ProductID with an input box and then let them know with a msgbox whether it was or was not found, but I can't get the code right. What am I doing wrong here? Totally lost (code below):

```
Sub test()

    Dim Worksheet As Range
    Dim ProductID As Variant

    ProductID = InputBox("Please enter the Product ID")

    With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1000")
        Set ProductID = .Find("ProductID", LookIn:=xlWhole)

        If found Then
            MsgBox ProductID("was Found")
        Else
            MsgBox ProductID & (" was NOT Found")
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim found As Range`, `Set found = .Find(ProductID, LookIn:=xlWhole)`, `If Not found Is Nothing Then`, `MsgBox ProductId &  "was Found"`, `Else`, `MsgBox ProductID & " was NOT Found"`

Comment: BigBen, thank you so much! When I try this, it says "invalid or unqualified reference" and highlights .Find.

Comment: Sub test()

Dim found As Range
Set found = .Find(ProductID, LookIn:=xlWhole)
If Not found Is Nothing Then
MsgBox ProductID & "was Found"

Else
MsgBox ProductID & " was NOT Found"

End Sub

Comment: You need the `With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1000")`, and the `End If` and `End With` afterwards.

Comment: If i wanted to reference the entire worksheet instead of A1:Z1000, how would i do that?

Comment: `With Worksheets(1).Cells`

Comment: It is still showing that same error? Here's what I have

Comment: Dim found As Range
Set found = .Find(ProductID, LookIn:=xlWhole)
With Worksheets(1).Cells

End If
End With

If Not found Is Nothing Then
MsgBox ProductID & "was Found"

Else
MsgBox ProductID & " was NOT Found"

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Several issues, including the following:

- Assign the result of the `Find` to a `Range` variable (separate from the `ProductId`), e.g. the variable `found`.
- Use `If Not` said variable `Is Nothing` to test if the find succeeded.
- Remove `Dim Worksheet As Range`.
- Variables don't belong inside quotes. `ProductID` (without quotes) is the variable. `"ProductID"` is the text "ProductID". Call `Find` using the variable, not the text.
- Should be `LookIn:=xlValues` or `LookIn:=xlFormulas`, then `LookAt:=xlWhole`.

```
Sub test()

    Dim ProductID As Variant
    ProductID = InputBox("Please enter the Product ID")

    Dim found As Range
    Set found = Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(What:=ProductID, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ProductID & " was Found"
    Else
        MsgBox ProductID & " was NOT Found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This brings me to 'run-time error 9, subscript out of range' and highlights:     Set ProductID = Worksheets(1).Cells.Find("ProductID", LookIn:=xlWhole)

Comment: Refresh the page. That line should read: `Set found = Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(What:=ProductID, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)`.